# ActionBarSherlock Fragments Tabs Looks Different in non-ICS versions of Android

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I've been going through the ABS Fragments demo, and noticed that the tabs look quite different in the older versions of Android - is this normal?  I took screenshots comparing the two, and particularly the tab looks different:

[image: comparison]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a TabWidget, not the action bar tabs. Look at the 'Tab Navigation' example in the 'demos' sample for the backported tabs.

Comment: Thanks Jake... and thanks for all your hard work with the ABS library!

Comment: I'll update the sample for the next release. It should be using the action bar tabs to further demonstrate the action bar usage.